# How to call a Php Function from html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am using a PHP **scraper** by using simple PHP DOM library. I wrote a function which **scrapes** data that I need. How can I call that function from html page? I need to show that data in my html page. I am using AngularJS framework and I am working with views.

Here is my code.

```
function Islamabad_data(){
    // Array Declaration
    var isb_hi_temp = new Array();
    $fhtml1 = file_get_contents('http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/daily-weather-forecast/258278');
    $fhtml1 = str_get_html($fhtml1);
    $day6 = file_get_contents('http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/daily-weather-forecast/258278?day=6');
    $day6 = str_get_html($day6);
    echo "Islamabad Data<br>";
    echo" <br>High temperature <br>";
    foreach($fhtml1->find('#feed-tabs .temp') as $element){
        echo $element->plaintext;
        ?>
            isb_hi_temp.push('<?php echo $element; ?>');
        <?php
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach($day6->find('#feed-tabs .temp')as $element)
    {
        if($i<2)
        {
            echo $element->plaintext;
            ?>
                isb_hi_temp.push('<?php echo $element; ?>');
            <?php
            $i++;                 
        }
    } 
    echo isb_data;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the Angular module and service code?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer but I've simplified your code.  It looks like you want to generate a JavaScript array that can be fetched by Angular.  Step 1 one is to properly generate the JSON you need.  There were a lot of mistakes in your code -- you cannot intermix JavaScript and PHP in the way that you were doing.  Usually in PHP we'll generate an array object using PHP then call json_encode to create the JSON object that will be accessed by the client (in this case, you are using Angular as your client).

```
function Islamabad_data(){
    $fhtml1 = file_get_contents('http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/daily-weather-forecast/258278');
    $fhtml1 = str_get_html($fhtml1);
    $day6 = file_get_contents('http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/daily-weather-forecast/258278?day=6');
    $day6 = str_get_html($day6);
    //echo "Islamabad Data<br>";
    //echo" <br>High temperature <br>";
    $hiTemp = array();
    foreach($fhtml1->find('#feed-tabs .temp') as $element){
        $hiTemp[] = $element;
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach($day6->find('#feed-tabs .temp')as $element) {
        if ($i<2) {
            $hiTemp[] = $element;
        }
        $i++;
    } 

    echo json_encode( $hiTemp );
}
```

Step 2.  Use Angular to call your PHP service.  Here is an oversimplified example to help you:

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/some/where/somefile.php').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.islamabadData = data;
        });
}
```

Also you should really be using Accuweather's API instead of doing data scraping.

http://apidev.accuweather.com/developers/

Comment: Thanks Clayton. but in my .php file i have multiple functins and each function is returning 3 arrays... is it possible to call that functions from angular ?

Comment: yes, look at my example. In Angular you use $http.get().  You will need to modify the code to be similar to what I posted for Angular to get everything in the proper format.

Comment: Thanks Clyaton, i have issue with using that function.

$http.get('/some/where/somefile.php').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.islamabadData = data;
        });

Answer (score 0):

It might help you:

```
function loadCitiesData($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/some/where/somefile.php?Islamabad=1').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.islamabadData = data;
        });

    $http.get('/some/where/somefile.php?Lahore=1').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.LahoreData = data;
        });
}
```

And your `somefile.php` file:

```
<?php

if( !empty($_GET['Islamabad']) ){

    $fhtml1 = file_get_contents('http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/daily-weather-forecast/258278');
    $fhtml1 = str_get_html($fhtml1);
    $day6 = file_get_contents('http://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/daily-weather-forecast/258278?day=6');
    $day6 = str_get_html($day6);
    //echo "Islamabad Data<br>";
    //echo" <br>High temperature <br>";
    $hiTemp = array();
    foreach($fhtml1->find('#feed-tabs .temp') as $element){
        $hiTemp[] = $element;
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach($day6->find('#feed-tabs .temp')as $element) {
        if ($i<2) {
            $hiTemp[] = $element;
        }
        $i++;
    } 

    echo json_encode( $hiTemp );
}elseif( !empty($_GET['Lahore']) ){
    // your code, $yourArray = array('something');
    // echo json_encode( $yourArray );
}elseif( !empty($_GET['Multan']) ){
    // your code, $yourArray = array('something');
    // echo json_encode( $yourArray );
}

?>
```